# Best way to send infrequently-changing JSON data to a client in production

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm developing an extremely JavaScript-heavy application using Rails 3.1. I have developed an "admin" area where the app can be configured by myself through a Web interface, using Rails models. This portion of the database is expected to change very infrequently, but I need to have the ability to change it, hence the admin.

I'm now working out the best way to get the data down to the browser. I need the client to load the data before the JavaScript application itself can be started, so I'd like to avoid any AJAX calls if possible, because these subsequent requests would have to be completed first.

Since the data rarely changes, it's a great candidate for caching -- but I can't make use of the asset pipeline in this case because I don't want to have to re-deploy the Rails app whenever the model data changes.

I can't use embedded ERB code in the assets either because, even if I don't precompile them, the actual asset file has to have changed before Rails will pick up the modifications. Even though the model data has changed, since the ERB code is not modified, Rails won't produce a new asset file for me, even if I touch the file (to update the timestamp), because its MD5 hash hasn't changed.

At this point I'm about to break down and embed the JSON models directly into the view templates, but I'm loathe to do this (separation of data and view, and all that).

Are there any better solutions, such as a programmatic way to force Rails/Sprockets to recompile a particular asset, or all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've decided to create a controller and JavaScript view for it, using `respond_to`. Example:

```
class ConfigurationController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |fmt|
      fmt.js
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The JS view for this controller spits out the model data:

```
<% InfrequentlyChangingModel.all.each do |record| %>
  AppData[<%= record.id %>] = (<%= record.to_json.html_safe %>);
<% end %>
```

Then in the front-end view I reference it like any other JavaScript file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'configuration' %>
```

I'm still open to other suggestions, but this is the cleanest and most Rails-like solution I've been able to come up with so far. It produces an extra request up-front (for the js file) but should cache pretty nicely and avoids extra AJAX.

Comment: I'm adding a version to my .erb that I bump when I want it to recompile (if there are no other changes).  Highly inelegant.